# Manually remove Windows 8 from Mac Book Pro (OS X 10.8.2 ML)

Tags: macos, windows-8, multi-boot, macbook-pro, boot-camp

Here's what I did:

- I wanted to try W8 on my MBP.
- installed W8 dualboot with bootcamp
- got fed up with W8 cause it wouldn't work as expected
- I deleted the Windows partition with the Disk Utility of Mac OS X

All went fine, until I restarted. 
I got a "bluescreen" telling me that "C:/somefile/etc..." couldn't be found.

So I thought it might be some leftover from Windows, and rebooted, holding the option-Key and choose the MAC-HD to boot from. 
That worked, and I changed the default boot volume to MAC-HD.

The problem is that sometimes when I wake from sleep, the MBP crashes. Or after installing an update I have to rechoose the default boot volume.

Now I want to remove that last bit of Windows that is still hovering somewhere.

How do I do that?

Some additional information:

```
$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI                         209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

MacBook Pro Retina 2012
500GB SSD / 16GB RAM
Mac OS X 10.8.2 Mt. Lion

Answer (score 0):

If you use Bootcamp Assistant and select the "Remove Windows 7" option only, this will remove the partition and put your whole system back to normal.

[image]

Comment: @David: I just started the assistant, but I don't see this screen. It looks like it does not recognize the windows boot partition without the actual windows partition.